# How to call a function from other script in LUA?

Tags: function, lua

I have a root folder named "root".
In this folder I have 2 more directories, each with one folder, each with a script:

```
/root/script01/client_script01/main.lua
```

In this script I have this:

```
local function OpenWindow()
    stuff
end
```

And

```
/root/script02/client_script02/main.lua
```

I want to use `OpenWindow()` function in second script!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you can call `OpenWindow`from `client_script02/main.lua` if you do not use the `local` keyword in the definition.

This however is not best practice. I am unsure of the specifics of your environment or intent, but in most cases it is better to create a lua module and use the `require` function to load it.

This is better because it shows the relationship between the files, showing that `client_script02/main.lua` requires `client_script01/main.lua` to be loaded to operate properly.

Your module could look something like this:

```
local client_script01 = {}

client_script01.OpenWindow = function()
    --stuff
end

return client_script01
```

The other script something like this:

```
local cs01 = require('client_script01')

do
    cs01.OpenWindow()
    --stuff
end
```

You would also need to adjust your file structures to better suit this convention, based on how the `require` function preforms searching: [lua-users - Package Path](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PackagePath)